# Ao editar a localização no perfil recebo esta mensagem "Não reconhecemos esse local"?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, perfil

Ao editar o perfil em `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/<seu id>` recebo esta mensagem:

[image: erro]

No SOen está funcionando normalmente:

[image: funcionando]

Ao exibir o console notei esta mensagem:

> ```
> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
> ```
>
> Fonte: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/10/util.js:208

E quando digito qualquer coisa aparece isto:

> ```
> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
> ```
>
> Fonte: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places:34

Acredito que só esteja faltando configurar a chave da API (que deve ser a mesma usada nos demais sites da rede, não tenho certeza).